# Set custom icon instead of Java one in Docks for own application. MacOS

Tags: java, macos, icons

I run my Java app in MacOS by executing sh-script that starts my jar-file.
Now in Dock the **icon for my app is Java** one:

[image]

How I can change this Dock's Java icon **to my custom icon**? What might be the solutions?

Comment: You could try that "prior research" thing. Like sending the question title to google before putting up a new question here.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks a lot. I have searched before, however missed this question.

Comment: Fine. Then remember to search a bit more the next time ;-) ... and decide for yourself if your question is "special" enough (I like the screenshot ;-) to be kept, or if you rather delete it now.